# Facebook login phonegap is lost when I change page

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using PhoneGap-Facebook-plugin, and it's working quite well, I have no problems to do the login and get access to the token. But when I change the html page (`window.location = 'page.html';`), and then I call `FB.getLoginStatus(...)` the response is that the user is not connected.

How can I solve this?

I also have to do `FB.init()` again each time I enter in a new html page because otherwise it throw the error: `FB.getLoginStatus() called before FB.init()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround will be to use local/session storage

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     if (response.status === 'connected') {
         window.sessionStorage.setItem("FBUserAuth", JSON.stringify(response.authResponse));
     // do your stuff
     });
```

to store the user authentication data and in your subsequent pages use ajax to access the Facebook graph APIs.